# Workflow suspends at read/edit list item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, item, item-level-permissions

**Working Scenario:**

- We have one list on which we have deployed one visual studio 2013 declarative workflow. workflow set to start on item added.
- On this list we have set "Item-Level-Permissions" to "Users can Read and Edit only their own items".
- Now whenever user creates a new item then workflow starts on behalf of that user, then do read/edit operations on list item & will get completed without any error.

**Problematic scenario:**

- when I go to manually start a workflow on items that were created by other users then workflow starts and get suspended with below error (`HTTP 404: Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user`). Error occurred at "`LookupSPListItem`" action which read current list item.

  ```
  RequestorId: 9ea19a57-ba73-bef6-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 {"error":{"code":"-1, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Item does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."}}} {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["1"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["86"],"SPRequestGuid":["9ea19a57-ba73-bef6-a69b-537372c36645"],"request-id":["9ea19a57-ba73-bef6-a69b-537372c36645"]
  ```
- If I change "Item-Level-Permissions" to "Read and edit all items" then workflow works fine & get completed without any error. But for security concerns we don't want to change this permissions.
- I also tried with creating & granting "Cancel Checkout" permissions to my account but it doesn't helped me out. (I'm site collection administrator, I have full control on site & lists).I also tried by string a workflow by system account but no luck.
- Workflow can use app permissions feature is activated on web.

How can I overcome this issue? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the issue, you could grant the user with read or edit permission on the item which is not created by the user by changing item permission before doing other actions in the workflow.

We can add “Replace List Item Permission” action in the impersonation step in workflow to change the item permission.  It only can work in workflow 2010.

For more detailed information, you could refer to the article below.

How to Create a Workflow to Change Item Level Permissions.

http://spcycle.blogspot.sg/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html